# How to rejoin the shattered objects in Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, blender

I am facing problem in rejoining the shattered objects in the unity.

1. The first i have shattered many objects in unity using gun.
2. Now i want to rejoin all shattered object that i broke previously(Kind of repairing it).

Kindly please help me with this issue

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code where the object is shattered?

Comment: `using System.Collections
using System.Collection.Genereic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Destructible : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject destroyedVersion;
    void OnMouseDown ()
    {
        Instantiate(destroyedVersion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to not fully destroy the gameObject, but to merely set it to be inactive, and store a reference to it somewhere else:

```
public class Destructible : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Class based on your code sample above.

    public GameObject destroyedVersion;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        GameObject destroyedObject = Instantiate(
            destroyedVersion, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        Destroyed destroyed = destroyedObject.GetComponent<Destroyed>();
        destroyed.SetOrigin(this);

        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

public class Destroyed : MonoBehavior
{
    Destructible destructible = null;

    public void SetOrigin(Destructible destructible)
    {
        this.destructible = destructible;
    }


    // This method can now be called from anywhere to rebuild:    
    public void RebuildOrigin()
    {
        if (destructible != null)
        {
            destructible.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Yet another approach, and it may be more maintainable, would be to give the original object -- e.g. Building -- an energy level or intact bool of some kind, and when it gets destroyed, you change its appearance and behavior.

Good luck!